# cant find Xsrf-Token on requests

Tags: performance, jmeter, software-quality

Im doing a login in jmeter

Previously i sent a request login [options] where i get the cookie and save in a header variable,,second request is the login[POST] request which has credentials as payload and i set the cookie from previous req and send as a header(CookieManager.save.cookies property is set to true),and it worked ok

But currently getting 403 errors on login on Jmeter,,on investigation on UI im seeing the request login [options] no longer has any token as a response,,,,but login[POST] somehow has the token already set on request and thus can login successfully

I have tried looking where the xrsf token is generated but cant seem to find it as a response to any of the requests,,,yet login,registration etc have it on their headers  on UI

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hKBA.png)

Answer (score 0):

keep cookie manager as global level, so that you dont need to pass via header manager to the every request level

Answer (score 0):

If you want us to help you in locating the token you need to provide a [.HAR file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format)) containing all the requests from your "login" transaction, it can be generated using [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools).

CSRF token doesn't necessarily come in a cookie, it can be in another [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), in the response body, even in the [redirection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) URL so pay attention to literally everything, I think it's in the response.

Check out:

- [Cross-Site Request Forgery Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html)
- [What is CSRF & How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-csrf-load-testing)

Comment: [.HAR file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QdI5O7xc1M3GRobRQ_L4Q3XeVP8miMZz/view?usp=sharing)  @Ivan G ,,in the cookie the value is XSRF-TOKEN-USERS and headers it is x-xsrf-token-users

Comment: but even from the .HAR ,,if you search the token,first place it appears is as a request token for login[POST]

Comment: token can be [percent-encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) for example, you can look for a partical token value containing the characters which don't require percent encoding. If this is the case you can use i.e. [__urlencode()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) or [__urldecode()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urldecode) functions as required. See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions) for more information on JMeter Functions concept. POST cannot be first request